# Hibernate query.stream() connection leak

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, hikaricp

I am using Spring Data JPA 2.7.6 with Hibernate 5.6.14, PostgreSQL driver 42.5.1 and HikariCP 4.0.3.

Inside a custom repository fragment implementation, I have a utility method that turns any given query into an "exists"-predicate. It used to look like this:

```java
    //using javax.persistence.Query
    private boolean exists(Query query) {
        query.setMaxResults(1);
        final List<?> result = query.getResultList();
        return !result.isEmpty();
    }
```

This worked perfectly, both inside and outside of transactions.

Now it got changed to use streams like this:

```java
    //using org.hibernate.query.Query
    private boolean exists(Query<?> query) {
        query.setMaxResults(1);
        try (Stream<?> result = query.stream()) {
            return result.findFirst()
                    .isPresent();
        }
    }
```

This works fine when called inside a transaction but causes connection leaks when called without one.

Usefulness of the streams code aside (I reverted the change), I would like to understand why this causes a leak to avoid similar issues in other contexts.

I would have expected the stream to get closed when exiting the try-block, and therefore no issues with the connection. Hibernate javadoc says

> You should call Stream.close() after processing the stream so that the underlying resources are deallocated right away.

which the try-block should guarantee.

Comment: `javac` does not generate such a warning. Various IDEs do, as do various linter tools. You should edit the question and mention the linter tool/IDE that is the source of this message, or add a tag. It sure sounds like that tool, whatever it might be, is to blame here.

Comment: @rzwitserloot do you mean the quote "You should call Stream.close()"? That's not a warning in the code, that's a quote from the javadoc. I was actually seeing the connection leaks in production, and Hikari's leak detection pointed at this method. It's reproducible simply by calling exists() a bunch of times without a transaction.